# Two columns of different data types concatenating in SSIS using pipeline delimiter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I am having 3 columns in source table and i want to load it to single column in destination with varchar data type. How to concatenate those columns using derived column. Please give your valuable suggestions

Regards,
Azarudhin Shaik.

Comment: Do you ever need the 3 columns separated in your data flow or will the concatenated value always be used? Do you need to worry about embedded pipes, and thus, escaping a pipe, in the source data?

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating three columns by drag and drop in an derived column expression. Make sure you convert these three columns before concatenation if they were not of type varchar.

Hope this helps.